# Typescript unable to do false check on unassigned object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert the following js into typescript but I'm having an issue with checking my `account` object as it is unassigned so the code won't build:

```js
const accounts = state.msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
let account;

if (accounts.length) {
  account = accounts[0];
} else {
  await state.msalInstance
    .handleRedirectPromise()
    .then(redirectResponse => {
      if (redirectResponse !== null) {
        account = redirectResponse.account;
      } else {
        state.msalInstance.loginRedirect();
      }
    })
    .catch(error) => {
      console.error(`Error during authentication: ${error}`);
    });
}

if (account) {}
```

The above works fine in js so I have converted it to the following ts, but now the final `if` won't compile as I'm trying to use the account variable before anything has been assigned to it:

```ts
const accounts = state.msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
let account: object;

if (accounts.length) {
  account = accounts[0];
} else {
  await state.msalInstance
    .handleRedirectPromise()
    .then((redirectResponse: {
      account: object;
    }) => {
      if (redirectResponse !== null) {
        account = redirectResponse.account;
      } else {
        state.msalInstance.loginRedirect();
      }
    })
    .catch((error: {
      name: string;
    }) => {
      console.error(`Error during authentication: ${error}`);
    });
}

if (account) {
  // this won't compile anymore as account isn't assigned
}
```

How do I change the `account` object so I can see if it is null or undefined? I tried setting it specifically as null but it says that I can't set an object to null.

Comment: `let account: object | null = null;`  or `let account: object | undefined;`

Comment: @Quentin `account` is different to `accounts`, but definitely easy to confuse the two

Comment: @MarkHanna — Ak. I looked at that so many times.

Comment: Thanks @Keith, I didn't realise you could assign multiple (I'm new to typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do ->

```
let account: object;

if (account) { // error here
```

Your telling Typescript that account can only be an `object`, but Typescript will let you delay assigning it, but if it detects that its possible to never assign an object to account it will give you -> `Variable 'account' is used before being assigned.`

Seen as your doing a truethy test -> `if (account) {`

The type your logically after is `object` or `undefined`

```
let account: object | undefined;

if (account) { // No error
```

In some cases it might make more sense been explicit about a value not been set, so some people also like to use `null` for this -> `let account:object | null = null`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem of not being able to use a variable before assigning it a value is quite simple - just assign it a value.

You could be explicit that its value is initially `undefined`, which is what happens to variables that have declared but not assigned a value. Or you could use a more deliberate "no value" initial value like `null`.

Of course, this will change your variable's type to be a union that includes this initial value, but that's consistent with how you're using it so I don't expect it would be a problem.

As a side note, `object` is not a great type to use. If you have linting in place you'll likely be warned about this. Would some form of [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) be more useful/clearer for you to use instead?